# How to decouple client from entity variable names when Spring JPA sorting is used

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA Pageable to manage the pagination and sorting for an endpoint. The issue is the client should use the same variable name for sorting as the entity name for JPA to be able to accept the sort request. However, I am trying to decouple the sort in the request from the entity so if the entity variable is renamed there is no impact on the request params.

```
@Entity
class Example {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;


    // constructor, getters etc.
}


// controller
@GetMapping("/examples")
public ResponseEntity<ExampleResponseModel> getAllExamples(
      @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "1") int pageNum,
      @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "10") int pageSize,
      @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "firstName, lastName") String[] sortFields,
      @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "asc") String sortOrder {
    Page<Example> pages = repository.findAll(PageRequest
            .of(pageNum - 1, pageSize, Sort.by(Direction.fromString(sortOrder), sortFields)));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(pages, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

One way could be implementing a mapping in the middle to translate the request model sort field names to Entity field names. However, this will be very verbose and does not solve the sorting sensitivity to the field name in the Entity class. My primary objective is to decouple the client from entity entirely when it comes to sorting and also make sure that if another developer renames `firstName` variable of `Example` class to `firstname` the sorting won't break (or at least he gets a compile-time error to notify him to fix it).

Comment: 'make sure that if another developer renames firstName variable of Example class to firstname the sorting won't break' - I mean, if you're returning entities from the controller, it's usually not just the sorting that will break if a property gets renamed. The question is, then, if it's really worth the effort trying to safeguard against sort property name changes. I would suggest an API contract test suite instead to make sure property names don't get changed *accidentally*.

Comment: @crizzis I removed service layer and corresponding models to simplify the code snippet, so entities are generally decoupled but that's not true for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

If you use paging and sorting I would guess that you have a grid or something similar at the frontend. If so, you can create your own annotation which would keep a meta-name of the property that wouldn't be changed whatever happened.
After that you should create a new `GET` method in the controller which would have requested all the metas and its real names read through the reflection. Entering the grid tab or whatever, front should, firstly, check its storge looking for metas of the `Example` entity. If succeed, just take this data and use in the request, if not, request the new endpoint to get metas with mapped real names and store it and only then make a request with sorting and paging. If front- and back and are independent then add actualization of metas while backend startup.

Comment: Not sure if I could understand your suggestion exactly. Could you elaborate more by sharing an example?